# Can I update OpenSUSE's version of Qt?

Tags: qt, updates, opensuse

I'm using OpenSUSE 11.2 which has Qt 4.5.3.

Can I update its Qt to version 4.6? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you want to update? I'd recommend keeping it as it is.

```
su root && zypper ref && zypper up
```

should update all your packages. I say all because there are lot of interdependencies on Qt version - I'd probably leave as it is.

Comment: I'm trying to build a code which was built with version 4.6. Which when I try to build gives me this error: QWSPointerCalibrationData: No such file or directory. And when I try using "#ifdef HAVE_Q_WS_QWS" to prevent this errors, I'm still getting a lot of errors related to it. :)